# Dynamic content in Dialog component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, primereact

Hello I try to make data view with prime react component in Dialog with dynamic photo size content. By default the photo popup with scroll bar and in the centre of screen. 
How to make it with dynamic size and without scrollbar and on top of the screen.

I tried to use max/min height and weight but there is no result.
Found "Dynamic content may move the dialog boundaries outside of the viewport. Common solution is defining max-height via contentStyle so longer content displays a scrollbar." from https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/dialog
But how implement it.

```
        <Dialog header="Client Details"
                visible={this.state.visible}
                modal={true}
                onHide={() => this.setState({visible: false})}>
            {this.renderClientDialogContent()}
        </Dialog>


renderClientDialogContent() {
    if (this.state.selectedClient) {
        return (
            <div className="p-grid" style={{fontSize: '16px', textAlign: 'center', padding: '20px', maxHeight:'800px', maxWidth:'700px', minWidth:'300px'}}>
                <div className="p-col-36" style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                    <img src={this.state.selectedClient.bigPhotoLink}
                         alt={this.state.selectedClient.name} />
                </div>

                <div className="p-col-12">{this.state.selectedClient.name}</div>

                <div className="p-col-12">{this.state.selectedClient.description}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

How to make dialog size equal photo size.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the `contentStyle` object with the desired `max-height`, (the same way you do with the `style` attribute):

```
<Dialog
    contentStyle={{ maxHeight: "300px" }}
    header="Client Details"
    visible={this.state.visible}
    modal={true}
    onHide={() => this.setState({visible: false})}
    >
    {this.renderClientDialogContent()}
</Dialog>
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you write how to make dialog size equal dynamic photo size?

Comment: you could limit the height of your image instead